# Using < Symbol in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible script I created that backs up a Databases, Destroys, Creates, and Points the back up to the newly created DB:

```
 - name: Backing up database
   command: pg_dump --schema-only --file=image.dump.20100217 image

 - name: Destroying Current Database
   command: time dropdb image

 - name: Creating Database
   postgresql_db: name=image
                  owner='ryan'

 - name: Pointing newly created DB to Backed up DB
   command: psql image < image.dump.20100217
```

Everything runs fine until it tries to point to the backed up DB. Ansible doesn't process the `<` symbol and ultimately crashes:

```
failed: [192.168.x.x] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["psql", "image", "<", "image.dump.20100217"], "delta": "0:00:00.003229", "end": "2015-08-19 11:26:21.796224", "rc": 2, "start": "2015-08-19 11:26:21.792995", "warnings": []}
stderr: psql: warning: extra command-line argument "image.dump.20100217" ignored
psql: FATAL:  role "<" does not exist

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not tested it but the ultimate trick with problematic characters is to put it into a Jinja expression:

```
command: psql image {{ "<" }} image.dump.20100217
```

---

I can't reproduce this in Ansible 1.9.2. Here is what I tested:

```
- command: echo psql image < image.dump.20100217
  register: x
- debug: var=x
```

Comment: I tried it, but that did not work unfortunately. Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: What version of Ansible are you running? I just tried this and I actually can not reproduce the issue in Ansible 1.9.2.

Comment: I mean, it not only works with the Jinja expression but also without, like in your original example.

Comment: I added the tasks I tested above. Does this work on your box?

Comment: Yes it does!! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Hmmm, but what is/was the issue then with your task without the `echo`?

Comment: Im not sure exactly. Im still novice with using ansible. I figured that this would be a problem with it processing symbols

Comment: I switched the command to shell.. However now I can't confirm if the database has been created..

Comment: If the command generates any output, you can check it the way I showed above with `register` and `debug`.

Comment: do you know if its possible to query a db using ansible/

Answer (score 1):

Use the module 'shell' instead of 'command'

```
---
name: Pointing newly created DB to Backed up DB
shell: psql image < image.dump.20100217
```

Comment: I actually used that command and it did work when I tried it so I stuck with it